# Not able to use pod dependency in Swift static library

Tags: swift, dependencies, static-libraries

I have built a static library in Swift, which internally uses Alamofire for network connections. I have used Pods to include this dependency and my idea is that host app (that will use my library) will add Alamofire dependency in itself and my static library will use the same.

But, I am facing issue while using this library inside other app. It gives me version mismatch error.

Any help in this regard will be helpful.